# S3 Paths | boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, yaml, boto3

I have a current process that reads in a data source directory via a yaml file designation:

```
with open (r'<yaml file>') as file:
    directory = yaml.load(file, Loader = yaml.FullLoader)

source_directory = directory['source_directory']
```

The yaml file reads as follows:

```
source_directory : '<directory>'
```

However, the data source has now shifted from a local directory to an S3 Bucket.  I am able to view the files in my S3 bucket by using the code below:

```
import boto3

def ListFiles(client):
    response = client.list_objects(Bucket = '<bucket name>')
    for content in response.get('Contents', []):
        yield content.get('Key')


file_list = ListFiles(client)
for file in file_list:
    print(file)
```

The boto3 code correctly lists my files, so I know my connection to the bucket is successful.  How do I reference the directory path within the S3 bucket in the variable `source_directory` in the yaml file?

---

Update based on a comment I got:

Someone suggested to use `s3://<bucket_name>/object_path` in place of the  call out in the yaml file.  However, this produces a `No such file or directory` error.

Comment: You can use `s3://<bucket_name>/object_path`, but you will need to parse this URI with urlparse or similar.

Comment: Could you provide an example by posting an answer? @jordanm

Comment: Note: your `ListFiles` method has a couple of issues. It's uses a legacy API (should use list_objects_v2) and it doesn't handle paginated results.

Comment: Which line of code "produces a No such file or directory error"? Your typical Python file i/o isn't going to work with an S3 URI. You're going to have to proxy that somehow e.g. using s3fs or roll your own (e.g. download the files from S3 locally).

Comment: Sorry, but what is your question? Are you having problem with reading the YAML file, or problems with obtaining the list of files from S3? Or is the problem that you need a Bucket _AND_ a Path?

Comment: I need to reference the path to the S3 bucket, which I'd like to place in my yaml file @JohnRotenstein

Comment: ```source_directory = directory['s3://<bucket_name>/object_path']``` produces the error, @jarmod.

Comment: If you would like to correct the ListFiles example, feel free to post an answer with an example, @jarmod

Comment: Afaik, `yaml.load(...)` returns a dictionary so `directory['xyz']` is simply accessing a key/value pair in the dictionary and cannot possibly result in a `No such file or directory` error. Are you sure that's the line of code that causes the error? Regardless, the point is that you cannot use regular file i/o with a native S3 URI.

Comment: What's the alternative option, if I cannot reference an S3 bucket's directory path within a yaml file? @jarmod

Comment: I answered that earlier: using s3fs or roll your own (e.g. download the files from S3 locally).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are wanting to obtain a list of objects in a given directory of an Amazon S3 bucket, you can use:

```
response = client.list_objects_v2(Bucket='<bucket name>',Prefix=source_directory)
```

The `Prefix` should end with a slash, so the YAML file should look like:

```
source_directory : 'my-directory/'
```